# Open file in browser

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, web

I would like the PDF to be displayed in the browser when the "a" tag is clicked, rather than being downloaded.

How do I change this code?

```
<a class="fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-3x attachFile" href="/gsuggestionsystem/Proposal/Desktop/GetFile/b57755fa-4f49-ee11-b365-005056b467aa?entityType=6" target="_blank" >    
    </a>
```

I expected the file to be displayed in the browser, but it was downloaded instead.

Comment: @KJ no no I don't have an "iframe"